# How to improve my linq to get values even if not all conditions are satisfied

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm working with list of products, it's simple table which displays all of my products.

Because there are many of them I included 4 dropdowns as a filters, where I might choose values to filter by, and it looks somehow like this:

[image]

Above dropdows I wrote what kind of data they hold so it will be easier to understand.

So for example If I select only Product and Payment to filter by my linq is not returning any values, that's because probably I said that all of the values must be met to get some data..

Here is the linq:

```
private Expression<Func<Product, bool>> GetFilter(Filter filterQuery)
{
    return f => (f.ProductId == filterQuery.ProductId) &&
                (f.LocationId == filterQuery.LocationId) &&
                (f.PaymentMethodId == filterQuery.PaymentMethodId) && ..sameForUser;
}
```

So how could I improve this linq to return values if `Product` and `Payment` only is selected, or to return values if only `Product` and Location is select, or all of them.. etc..

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can include the record by default if no option is chosen from the various filters. Something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<Product, bool>> GetFilter(Filter filterQuery)
{
    return f => (filterQuery.ProductId.HasValue ? f.ProductId == filterQuery.ProductId : true) &&
                (filterQuery.LocationId.HasValue ? f.LocationId == filterQuery.LocationId : true) &&
                (filterQuery.PaymentMethodId.HasValue ? f.PaymentMethodId == filterQuery.PaymentMethodId : true) && ..sameForUser;
}
```

This assumes that your various `Id`s will be null if no value is selected. It isn't clear from your question what is being used to represent no option being selected (null, 0, etc) however the concept will remain the same: include them if no option is selected or if there is a selection, match on the selected ID. Obligatory note: I personally (just my opinion) find the way this method is written to be hard to read and would probably refactor out the return lambda expression for readability's sake.

Comment: what about condition `( !filterQuery.ProductId.HasValue ||  f.ProductId == filterQuery.ProductId)` ? I test both of them and seems like they works (my and yours) :)

Comment: yes that's what I had at first actually and edited to what it is now. both will work and i'd opt for the expression in your comment. changed to the ternary bc i felt it more explicitly demonstrated either including the result or filtering based on id

Answer (score 1):

Check the generated SQL for that method.  If you build up all the conditional logic inside the Expression, the whole thing will get converted to SQL.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId],
    [Extent1].[LocationId] AS [LocationId],
    [Extent1].[PaymentMethodId] AS [PaymentMethodId]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ((CASE WHEN (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL) THEN CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[ProductId] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[ProductId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT (([Extent1].[ProductId] = @p__linq__1) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[ProductId] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (@p__linq__1 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END ELSE cast(1 as bit) END) = 1) AND ((CASE WHEN (@p__linq__2 IS NOT NULL) THEN CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[LocationId] = @p__linq__3) OR (([Extent1].[LocationId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__3 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT (([Extent1].[LocationId] = @p__linq__3) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[LocationId] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (@p__linq__3 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END ELSE cast(1 as bit) END) = 1) AND ((CASE WHEN (@p__linq__4 IS NOT NULL) THEN CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[PaymentMethodId] = @p__linq__5) OR (([Extent1].[PaymentMethodId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__5 IS NULL))) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT (([Extent1].[PaymentMethodId] = @p__linq__5) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[PaymentMethodId] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN (@p__linq__5 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END ELSE cast(1 as bit) END) = 1)
```

A better strategy is to add to the query Expression only for active filter criteria. 
 A simple implementation would be something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Ef6Test
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public int PaymentMethodId { get; set; }

    }

    static class FilterExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, Filter<T> filter)
        {
            return filter.ApplyTo(q);
        }
    }
    abstract class Filter<T>
    {
        public abstract IQueryable<T> ApplyTo(IQueryable<T> q);
    }
    class ProductFilter : Filter<Product>
    {
        public int? ProductId { get; set; }
        public int? LocationId { get; set; }
        public int? PaymentMethodId { get; set; }

        public override IQueryable<Product> ApplyTo(IQueryable<Product> q)
        {
            if (ProductId.HasValue)
            {
                q = q.Where(p => p.ProductId == this.ProductId);
            }
            if (LocationId.HasValue)
            {
                q = q.Where(p => p.LocationId == this.LocationId);
            }
            if (PaymentMethodId.HasValue)
            {
                q = q.Where(p => p.PaymentMethodId == this.PaymentMethodId);
            }
            return q;
        }
    }

    class Db : DbContext
    {

        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }


        class Program
        {


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

                using (var db = new Db())
                {
                    db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                    db.Database.Initialize(false);


                    var filter = new ProductFilter();
                    filter.LocationId = 2;

                    var q = db.Products.Where(filter);


                    var sql = q.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(sql);
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }




        }
    }
}
```

Which generates a nice, clean SQL query like this:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId],
    [Extent1].[LocationId] AS [LocationId],
    [Extent1].[PaymentMethodId] AS [PaymentMethodId]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[LocationId] = @p__linq__0
```

Comment: I was debating whether to comment on this approach rather than the rather common "build an expression tree" mechanism that comes up on SO rather often. +1 on this approach since it results in much more streamlined SQL. Something that shouldn't be dismissed for being a little extra, not as clever looking code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the improvements would be to create a function that does what you want.

It seems that you have an input sequence of `Products`, and you want to filter this input sequence to keep only those `Products` that match some predicate.

You are not really interested in creating an `Expression`. After all, this `Expression` will only be used in a `Where` statement to get the subset of `Products`.

So first of all: you need to create a function that returns an `IQueryable<Product>` instead of `Expression<Product>`.

We'll write it as an extension function of `Product`. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static class ProductExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Product> Filter(this IQueryable<Product> products,
                                             Filter filter)
    {
        // TODO: implement
    }
}
```

Usage will be:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    Filter filter = ReadFilterComboBoxes();
    var result = dbContext.Products.Filter(filter);
}
```

If desired you can use this as any other LINQ function:

```
var result = dbContext.Products.Where(product => ...)
                               .Filter(productFilter)
                               .Select(product => )
                               .GroupBy(...);
```

Apparently you have a class `Filter` that contains values of properties that be used as a predicate in the `Where` in your query. But somehow you want to say: "don't use this property in the filter, because the operator didn't select any value in the combo box"

To indicate that the operator didn't select any value, you could use NULL. For this you need to make the properties nullable. See [how to use nullable values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types)

Classes are always nullable. You make a value type (int, double, structs, enums) nullable by adding a question mark to the type:

```
class Filter
{
    public int? ProductId {get; set;}
    public int? LocationId {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Now you can say that a property should not be used because the operator didn't select the a value in the combo box by assigning null:

```
Filter selectedFilter = new Filter()
{
     ProductId = null; // operator didn't select the userId combo
     LocationId = LocationCombo.SelectedValue;
     ...
}
```

Depending on the type of combo boxes that you are using, SelectedValue may already have a value null if nothing is selected, otherwise you have to check yourself:

```
ProductId = ProductCombo.IsValueSelected ?? ProductCombo.Value : null;
```

Now that you've changed the `Filter` class, it is easy to implement the `Filter` method

```
 public static IQueryable<Product> Filter(this IQueryable<Product> products, Filter filter)
    {
        // TODO: exception if products == null

        if (filter == null)
        {
            // don't filter, return the original collection:
            return products;
        }
        else
        {
            return products.Where (product =>
                 (filter.ProductId == null || filter.ProductId == product.ProductId)
              && (filter.LocationId == null || filter.LocationId == product.LocationId)
              && ...);
        }
}
    }
```